# Coffeescript error in expressjs: unexpected ' (quote)

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I'm making an app in express.js, here's my app.coffee file:

```
###
Module dependencies.
###
express = require("express")
routes = require("./routes")
user = require("./routes/user")
http = require("http")
path = require("path")
app = express()

# all environments
app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
app.set "view engine", "jade"
app.use express.favicon()
app.use express.logger("dev")
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
app.use app.router
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))

# development only
app.use express.errorHandler()  if "development" is app.get("env")

mongoose = require 'mongoose'
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/temp', (err)->
    console.log(err) if err?
    console.log 'Connected'

app.get "/", routes.index

user = require './models/user'
users = require './controllers/users'
app.get '/users', users.list
app.post '/user', users.add
app.get '/user/:id', users.find
app.put '/user/:id', users.update
app.del '/user/:id', users.delete

http.createServer(app).listen app.get("port"), ->
  console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get("port")
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
app.coffee:1:16: error: unexpected '
###
               ^
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your other files, line 16.
There's currently a bug in coffeescript that makes it unable to report the correct filename when `require`-ing. It's fixed on master.

Comment: this is why I love SO